Generating OAuth token for LinkedIn App fails - page freezes
I am trying to access LinkedIn API to my own profile only. I already have created an app on LinkedIn. When I try to "Generating your OAuth token", from the Auth menu in the LinkedIn App page, it asks for my password, and then freezes forever or shows an error page with "Page not found" I have triple checked, the password I entered in correct. Could anyone help?
I have retried multiple times without any success.
